# Travis configuration for composer packages

Tags: php, unit-testing, package, laravel-5, travis-ci

While working on a laravel 5.1+ package I have this need to run automated tests through travis-ci.org. The difference with regular automated tests is the requirement to include this package into a framework and set specific configuration options to run the tests.

So the requirement would be:

- install laravel
- add my package as dependency
- set some travis specific configurations like the travis database access
- run migrations of laravel
- run migrations specific for package or run an artisan command
- run package specific unit tests

I searched everywhere; asked on [laravel forums](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/travis-configuration-for-laravel-packages), asked in a travis community chat and saw [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070228/is-there-a-standard-skeleton-or-instructions-for-setting-up-an-open-sourced-sy) being closed as too localized (although an answer would have certainly been helpful now). I'm hoping my question is fit to remain open.

At this time I have the following configuration:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.5
  - 5.6
  - hhvm

addons:
  hosts:
    - system.hyn.me
    - tenant.hyn.me

before_install:
  - sudo composer self-update

install:
  - composer create-project laravel/laravel
  - cd ./laravel
  - composer require hyn-me/multi-tenant ~0.1.0
  - composer update


before_script:
  - cp .env.travis .env
  - export APP_ENV="testing"
  - php artisan migrate -q -n --path ./vendor/hyn-me/multi-tenant/src/migrations
  - cd ./vendor/hyn-me/multi-tenant

script: phpunit
```

Yet my knowledge of travis (thus far) is limited and before I send in an unneeded number of commits to fix my problems I'd rather have your opinion on what would be a good method to test integration into a framework.

Ps. this concerns the package [hyn/multi-tenant](http://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant).

Advise on how to keep this question as generic as possible would be helpful. I hope without explicitly mentioning best practice and requesting integration into framework examples helps in defining the scope of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after weeks of pushing commits into travis, I finally made this work.

The .travis.yml:

```
language: php

sudo: true

php:
  - 5.5
  - 5.6
  - 7.0
  - hhvm

addons:
  hosts:
    - system.hyn.me
    - tenant.hyn.me

install:
  # fix ipv6 issue that prevented composer requests and resulted in failing builds
  - sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100' >> /etc/gai.conf"
  # updates composer on travis
  - travis_retry composer self-update
  # clear composer cache, might speed up finding new tags
  - travis_retry composer clear-cache
  # set the global github token, so connections won't be cancelled
  - composer config -g github-oauth.github.com $GITHUB_TOKEN
  # create a new database for the hyn connection
  - mysql -e 'create database hyn;' -uroot
  - mysql -e "grant all privileges on *.* to 'travis'@'localhost' with grant option;" -uroot
  # create a new laravel project in the subfolder laravel (default composer behaviour)
  - composer create-project laravel/laravel
  # set global variables
  - export DB_USERNAME=travis DB_DATABASE=hyn DB_PASSWORD= QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

script:
  # run the script calling unit tests and so on
  - ./scripts/travis.sh

after_script:
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION != '7.0' ]]; then php vendor/bin/ocular code-coverage:upload --format=php-clover ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/coverage.clover; fi
```

And the scripts/travis.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# e causes to exit when one commands returns non-zero
# v prints every line before executing
set -ev

cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/laravel

BRANCH_REGEX="^(([[:digit:]]+\.)+[[:digit:]]+)$"

if [[ ${TRAVIS_BRANCH} =~ $BRANCH_REGEX ]]; then
    echo "composer require ${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}:${TRAVIS_BRANCH}"
    composer require ${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}:${TRAVIS_BRANCH}
else
    echo "composer require ${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}:dev-${TRAVIS_BRANCH}"
    # development package of framework could be required for the package
    composer require hyn-me/framework "dev-master as 0.1.99"
    composer require "${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}:dev-${TRAVIS_BRANCH}#${TRAVIS_COMMIT}"
fi

# moves the unit test to the root laravel directory
cp ./vendor/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}/phpunit.travis.xml ./phpunit.xml

phpunit
# phpunit --coverage-text --coverage-clover=${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/coverage.clover
```

This code might change due to new Laravel versions or changes in travis. If this is the case, you will find the latest release [here](https://github.com/lara-league/multi-tenant).